# SOAP client, wsdl, python

Tags: php, python, web-services, soap, suds

I have SOAP service with WSDL and php-client for it.

Php-client:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://xx.xx.xx.xx/service/?wsdl');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://mfisoft.ru/auth','Login','admin');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://mfisoft.ru/auth','Password','admin');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
$table_hi = $client->getTableByTitle('Blocked numbers');
$row_data = array(
    array(
                      array(
                              'name' => 'prfx',
                              'value' => '55555555'
                       ),
                      array(
                              'name' => 'blocking_time',
                              'value' => '20140306185014'
                       )

)
);

$rowset=$client->insertRowset($table_hi, $row_data);
?>
```

But I need to rewrite the python.
I tried to do using suds and pysimplesoap.

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://localhost/service/?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
```

I don't understand how make similar program in particular these strings

```
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://mfisoft.ru/auth','Login','admin');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://mfisoft.ru/auth','Password','admin');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

I have not found in suds doc.
I need your help.

Thanks in advance.

p.s.
Sorry for my bad English

P.S.S.

I need to rewrite the php client in the python client.

Comment: I am confused. are you trying to make a soap client or a soap server in python?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the formatting in advance.. the proper way to setup and connect using the suds client is as follows. In the case that you want the server part, I can't tell 100% from your question.. I might be able to help but it's not something I've ever done before in python.

```
client = suds.client.Client.(self,url=wsdl_url,
                             doctor=schema_doctor,
                             username=username)
try:
    # This will throw an Exception if the wsdl_url is bad
    # and will return False if the authentication fails
    if not client.service.Connection_Authenticate(username,
                                                  password):
        raise Exception("Failed to authenticate.")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it does not work.
I need soap client.
WSDL file is located https://some_ip_adress/service/?wsdl